# Unable to Start a PowerShell ForEach Loop with a Variable

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

As you can tell by the snippet below, I am new to PowerShell. I'm trying to run a command using a variable for the drive letter where the tools are running from. I get an error:

> unexpected token in expression statement 'tools\perl_5.20.2.1\bin\perl.exe'

This script works fine if I hardcode the drive letter. Can someone suggest another way?

```
$OutDrive = Read-Host -Prompt 'Please select a drive letter to create output     folders (e.g. c:)'

$ntuser = Get-ChildItem -Force $outdrive\Folder\$ComputerName-$Date\users |
      Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer} | 
      foreach {$_.Name}

foreach ($Name in $ntuser){
    **$OutDrive\tools\perl_5.20.2.1\bin\perl.exe c:\tools\somescript**     $Outdrive\Folder\$ComputerName-$Date\users\$Name\ntuser.dat -f ntuser Out-File -   FilePath $Outdrive\FOlder\$ComputerName-$Date\users\$Name\$Name-blah.txt
}
```

Comment: Put quotation marks around the argument to `Get-ChildItem`

Comment: While you should put quotes around the `Get-ChildItem` argument that doesn't appear to be the problem causing the error.  is that `foreach` supposed to be all on one line with no pipes like that? the code as posted at minimum needs a `|` before the Out-File.

Comment: been using >> instead of | Out-File which seems to work fine when I have the drive letter hardcoded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
& "$OutDrive\tools\perl_5.20.2.1\bin\perl.exe" ......
```

Comment: tried & "$OutDrive\tools\perl_5.20.2.1\bin\perl.exe" ...... and now get the error - & : The term 'd:\tools\perl_5.20.2.1\bin\perl.exe is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.